# Send usb package osx

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

I need send package to my connected USB device. I have `javascript` function and even find [c# function](http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/html/59b69ac6-c868-22e2-5c92-f4163192bd52.htm), but i didn't find any `obj-c` or `swift` analogues:

```
chrome.usb.controlTransfer(self.handle, {         
    'direction':'in',         
    'recipient':'device',         
    'requestType':  'standard',         
    'request':      6,         
    'value':        0x300 | index,         
    'index':        0,  // specifies language         
    'length':       255 // max length to retreive     
}, function (result) {});
```

I did connection, so i have `var device : IOHIDDevice` device. But can't find function, how to send.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, sorry, i found it on apple site https://developer.apple.com/reference/iokit/iousbdevrequest?language=objc